# How to repair IIS when it loses its configuration?

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

I am working with IIS Manager 8.5 on Windows 8.1 x64. I have been using this installation for more than half a year for developing a large web-app. Everything was configured based upon an internal step-by-step guide on how to set up development machines.

All of a sudden, my local installation of the web-app has started returning 503 (the only recent changes I have made since it still worked were a few modifications to JavaScript files delivered as a part of the web application). While trying to figure out the cause by means of the *Failed Request Tracing* module, the following new issues appeared in IIS Manager:

- Clicking on the *Application Pools* node in the *Connections* tab gives me an empty list. I am pretty sure there was at least one item in there before.

  - When trying to re-add an application pool according to the aforementioned step-by-step guide, IIS Manager refuses to do so and says an application pool of that name is already existing.
  - When adding an application pool with a different name (say, *pool_A*), the *OK* button in the *Add application pool* dialog box gets greyed out upon clicking it, but the dialog box never disappears.
- Clicking on the *Sites* node in the *Connections* tab gives me an empty list. Trying to expand the *Sites* node in the *Connections* tab will make IIS Manager freeze (i.e. *busy* cursor and no response).

I could find an `applicationHost.config` file that appears to contain the server configuration. It was last changed today, and it did contain *pool_A*. It is a well-formed XML file.

Rebooting the machine doesn't help. Rebooting the server causes endless wandering of the green status indicator, until finally, an error message is displayed, saying that the service W3SVC cannot be launched.

**How can I proceed to debug this problem and find out what exactly is wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve the issue now: The problem seems to have been the *W3SVC* service stuck in *terminating* state.

When looking at that service in the *Services* tab of the task manager, or in the *Services* manager in the control panel, its state is shown as "terminating"/"being terminated" ("wird beendet" in my German Windows version). Accordingly, all options for stopping or restarting the service are greyed out (hence, [this related answer](https://superuser.com/a/393409/139558) did not help). However, this state appears to be permanent - it even survives Windows reboots.

I have applied [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6297173/1430156) to kill the service via the console:

```
C:\Users\mapper>sc queryex w3svc

SERVICE_NAME: w3svc
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 3  STOP_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x161
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x4e20
        PID                : 2356
        FLAGS              :
```

I then found the process ID *2356* (as listed above, will be different in every case) in the *Processes* list of task manager and terminated that process.

After this, I went back to the *Services* list, where the service was now in *being executed* state. The web application can be opened again on my machine, and IIS Manager has stopped crashing/freezing.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to do is look in `C:\inetpub\history\` there are x folders `CFGHISTORY_0*` with the last x configurations of IIS.

I would to a diff on some `ApplicationHost.config` and the current one in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config` and see what changed.

You can either manually fix it or restore a config from the history.

It is possible that your problems have nothing to do with ApplicationHost.config, but this would be I first guess.

Normally if the ApplicationHost.config is not well formed, IIS Manager will tell you that, the fact that it doesn't show items and hangs, is not a good sign.

Comment: "if the ApplicationHost.config is not well formed, IIS Manager will tell you that" - well, it *is* well-formed (Xml-wise, that is - no idea whether the contents lives up to IIS' expectations). In any case, +1 for the effort, even though I solved the issue differently, as described in [my answer](http://serverfault.com/a/797091/148948).